# Characters of subgroups of finite abelian groups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, abelian-groups, characters

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $\hat{G}$ be the group of characters of $G$. Is there a character $\chi \in \hat{G}$ such that $\chi(g) = 1$ iff $g \in H$?

Comment: Hint: What would this say about $G$ if $H$ was the trivial subgroup?

Comment: That there is a character $\chi \in \hat{G}$ such that $\chi(1_G) = 1$ and $\chi(g) \not= 1$ elsewhere? Not sure what I can conclude from this.

Comment: Translate that back, using the definition of a character. So the corresponding map to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is injective. What finite groups are subgroups of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$?

Comment: Finite abelian groups.

Comment: No, not all finite abelian groups are subgroups of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

Comment: The cyclic groups

Comment: Exactly, so if a character as the one you mention exists with $H$ being the trivial subgroup, you must have that $G$ is cyclic. Does this give you an idea as to what conditions are needed for a general $H$?